# How is misinformation moderated?

Tags: discussion

I see a number of questions on this site with incorrect answers. The incorrect answers are the most up-voted ones and sometimes even accepted by the original posters. In all of these instances the 'top' answer is based on a common misconception about the database platform or SQL in general. In some instances people have written in the comments calling out the misconception, but the answer remains the top voted, accepted answer.

If they are not moderated it feels to me that this is a fundamental flaw in the system. Imagine if a site like this had existed when people still thought the sun revolved around the earth. The "Earth Revolves around the Sun" answer would have nothing but down-votes, while a "Sun Revolves Around the Earth" answer would be accepted.

http://www.theonion.com/article/correct-theory-discarded-in-favor-of-more-exciting-3152

So my question is, how is this mis-information moderated? Can the incorrect accepted answers be flagged or deleted? Do moderators make periodic passes?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54306/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-sontum-how-is-misinformation-moderated).

Answer (score 17):

> Can the incorrect accepted answers be flagged or deleted?

### No, almost never.

As it says in the Stack Exchange FAQ [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (emphasis added):

> For answers, any post that is not an answer (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. **Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted.**

Wrong answers are useful for multiple reasons, including as examples of what not to do, to highlight a common misconception...and so on. Like any user with the [Vote Down privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), you can downvote any answer that you believe is incorrect. Every user with this privilege gets the same single vote.

In very rare cases, answers that not just wrong but *actually exceptionally harmful* may be deleted by moderators. Wrongly deleted material may likewise be undeleted.

Answers that [are not answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) can be flagged (by anyone with the [Flag Posts privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)) and deleted (by moderators or users with the [Trusted User privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).

Moderators cannot change whether an answer is 'accepted' or not. That is [for the question asker to decide](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally.

---

Related meta Q & A:

- [Why shouldn't I delete wrong answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264293/194636)
- [When or should you delete your incorrect answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37738/194636)
- [What is the rationale behind only downvoting incorrect answers instead of voting to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163900/194636)
- [Blatantly wrong accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78438/194636)
- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/194636)